# Different language support for JQVMap

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, I am using http://jqvmap.com/ it is very nice plugin but I want to set a parameter for language so that I have same map for different languages.

The core script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: '#333333',
            color: '#ffffff',
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            selectedColor: '#666666',
            enableZoom: true,
            showTooltip: true,
            values: sample_data,
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'             
        });
    });
    </script>
```

for test I added **language: 'Czech'** / **lang: 'Czech'** at last but it does not work I also read their document but it is not there.

Yes i found a file where all countries available in English version now I need to make some other language version can some body help me for this?

I need all countries name in Czech, Chinese(Simplified), Germany, Polish & Russion.

script is available in **jquery.vmap.world** file where all countries name with **en** version are passed like `"name":"Pakistan"}` and if I translate it into other language let say `Pákistán` or `巴基斯坦` javascript does not allow to save and browser shows `???` though I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/myscript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

[image]

okay if I remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` from html file then it works fine but all content of web page get mass.

I also tried `<iframe>` and load map source code but same issue..

any idea

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is show a different map, just pass a variable as value into the options

```
var maps={
   'en':'world_en',
   'Czech': 'world_cz',
   'Polish': 'world_po'
}

var lang ='Czech'/* logic to determine language in page*/

jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: maps[lang]

})
```

Comment: Yap buddy but how could I translate world_en into world_cz, world_po?

Comment: you have to define the values somewhere like in the object I created. How does your page flag the current language? You can pass the language to js `lang` variable from server if that helps

Comment: okay if I remove <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> then it works fine but all content of web page get mass.

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks like in order to help. Removing `meta charset` makes little sense. Have you set a javascript variable with language ?

Answer (score 0):

if someone has this issue, i've solve it by changing the file enconding to UTF-8 without BOM. Then i changed to that weren't showing up back to their original.

Hope if helps someone with this similar issue.